# Is there a way to prevent CMake find_package to display its message

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to **not** display message outputed during the execution of `find_package`?

---

Example:

I am using an external library that uses a lot of `message(STATUS ...)` and I am linking my executable to this library via something like:

```
find_package(REALLY_VERBOSE_LIBRARY)
target_link_libraries(myApp PRIVATE REALY_VERBOSE_LIBRARY:LIBRAY)
```

Then, in the output I get a lot of "messages" that come from the execution of `find_package` in this external library.

I hope this is clear!

Answer (score 0):

**One observation**

In your second line, I think you misspelled name of `target_link_libraries` function

**Answer to your question**

You can use `QUIET` option from [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#id2#:%7E:text=QUIET) to prevent displaying error messages dumped from this function

Comment: Thank you for the answer (i'll edit the typos). I understand that `QUIET` can prevent displaying error messages but what I want is to prevent displaying all of the messages emitted during the execution of the command `find_package`.

Comment: @KilianDemeulemeester: `QUIET` is *intended* to affect on **all messages**, not only on error ones. However, the function `find_package` actually executes some module or config script some of which are not controlled by CMake developers. If such script doesn't preserve QUIET semantic and e.g *unconditionally* calls `message()`, then such output cannot be supressed.